# tcp indicating end of stream

Tags: c, tcp, stream

I am having trouble ending tcp stream. I am writing a simple server and client where the client connects to the server and the server displays a welcome message asking the client for a username.

The problem is, when the server writes the message, the client's read() gets  blocked. It only gets unblocked when I call shutdown().

Server:

```
           if (FD_ISSET(tcp_listenfd, &rset)) {
                  len = sizeof(cliaddr);
                  if ((new_confd = accept(tcp_listenfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &len)) < 0) {
                            perror("accept");
                            exit(1);
                  }
                  /* Send connection message asking for handle */
                  writen(new_confd, handle_msg, strlen(handle_msg));
                  /* Fork here or shutdown fd is inherited */
                  shutdown(new_confd, SHUT_WR);
```

Clients:

```
    if ((connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))) < 0) {
            perror("inet_wstream:connect");
            exit(1);
    }

    s_welcome_msg[19] = '\0';
    readn(sock, s_welcome_msg, 20); //Blocks here if shutdown() is not called in server
```

The `readn()` and `writen()` functions are adapted from "The Socket Networking API" by Stevens found here: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169505&seqNum=9

How do I write a welcome message from the server without calling `shutdown()` and not having the client block? If more context is needed, I will post more code.

Comment: That `readn` function will not return until it actually reads 20 bytes (or it gets EOF, which is what you are causing by shutting down the sending side). This is probably not what you want. You need to decide how the client will know when it sees the end of a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `readn()` is designed to `read()` in a loop until either 20 bytes are read or there's EOF or an error on the socket. If the message the server sends is less than 20 bytes long, the client will block waiting for more data.

To prevent it from blocking, you could do a normal `read()` (or `recv()`) on the socket instead. In this case, that is likely to do what you want.

In general, you can't rely on being able to pair up `write()`s and `read()`s for TCP connections though. A single `write()` of a string "bar" could split the data up arbitrarily. As an extreme example, three successive `read()`s might return "b", "a", and "r". That particular example is unlikely, but for larger `write()`s and `read()`s you have to take this into account (and for smaller transmissions too, if you want to be perfectly safe).

To work around this issue, you will have to do your own buffering on the receiving end. The simplest solution in this case is to `read()` one character at a time (or to use `readn()` with exactly the amount of data you expect, if it is known). A more general solution is to `read()` as much data as is currently available (make sure to check the return value of `read()` to see how much data you get back!) into a buffer and only acting on the data whenever you've collected enough of it. A plain `read()` will not block as long as there's *some* data available to be read, but you might get back less data than you requested.

"Enough of it" would usually be a full "message" in your protocol. You will need some way to determine message boundaries. Two alternatives are length fields (usually the best solution in my experience) or message terminators. Both would be sent along with the rest of the data.

**Update**:

You have a bug in your null-termination logic by the way. Reading twenty bytes into `s_welcome_msg` will set `s_welcome_msg[19]` to the last byte read, overwriting your null terminator. If you want to read a 20-byte non-null-terminated string into `s_welcome_msg` and null-terminate it, `s_welcome_msg` will need to be 21 bytes long, and you will need to do `s_welcome_msg[20] = '\0'`.

Answer (score -2):

read(n) will block until it receives the requested number of bytes

(and the receiving field is only 19 bytes, so it it did read 20 bytes
that would be a buffer overflow which is undefined behaviour and can/will result in a seg fault event)

I suggest, as one possible fix, a loop with a select() statement with a timeout
    and when select() indicates some data available,
       read only one byte 
       append that byte to the s_welcome_msg[] buffer

(while always checking that the buffer is not overflowed
which, generally, would mean only read a max of 18 bytes
so the read value would be a valid string)

Your code should make the read() be non-blocking
so it will not hang.

After reading the byte, 
    if input buffer not full (18 bytes read)
    then loop back to the select() statement

If the select() timeout occurs, 
    then assume all the data has been read
    and proceed to the next code statements after the select/read loop

Also remember to always 'refresh' the timeout value
    on the select() statement parameter before 
    executing the select()

Comment: `read()`  blocks until it transfers *at least one byte,* or end of stream or an error occurs. All the OP has to do is specify the correct buffer length: reading an single byte at a time is a ridiculous suggestion, and will perform very poorly. And don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.